# Relationship between a table and a sql view

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm working with Gorm in my Go project. I'm reading a SQL view this way:

```
type Os struct {
    NOs         string    `json:"n_os" gorm:"column:OSRV"`
    DataOs      time.Time `json:"data_os" gorm:"column:DTA_CHAM"`
    Descricao   string    `json:"descricao" gorm:"column:MOT_MANT"`
    Fornecedor  string    `json:"fornecedor" gorm:"column:NM_FRNC"`
    Localizacao string    `json:"localizacao" gorm:"column:Localizacao"`
    Cidade      string    `json:"cidade" gorm:"column:NM_MUN"`
    Uf          string    `json:"uf" gorm:"column:SG_UF"`
    Tipo        string    `json:"tipo" gorm:"column:NOM_ITEM"`
    Situacao    string    `json:"situacao" gorm:"column:DESC_SITU"`
    Depreciacao string    `json:"depreciacao" gorm:"column:DEPRECIACAO"`
    Nbem        string    `json:"n_bem" gorm:"column:NRO_UNIV"`
}

func (Os) TableName() string {
    return "ordensServico"
}
```

This is working just fine. My problem is when I make a relationship between this model and another one. Like this one:

```
type Laudo struct {     
    gorm.Model  
    NumOsID           string        `json:"num_os"` 
    DataLaudo         time.Time    `json:"data_laudo"`  
    JustificativaID   int          `json:"JustificativaID"` 
    Justificativa     Justificativa`gorm:"foreignKey:JustificativaID"`  
    FunciAcompanhante string       `json:"funci_acompanhante"`  
    SituacaoID        int          `json:"situacaoID"`  
    Situacao          Situacao     `gorm:"foreignKey:SituacaoID"`   
    Anexos            []Arquivo    `json:"anexos"`  
    Os                Os           `json:"os"`
}
```

I this case, I get the following error:

> [error] invalid field found for struct laudosCondenacao/models.Laudo's field Os: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

I've tried to use de propriety "ForeignKey", but without success.

I would like to read information from the view from the table, like `Laudo.Os.Cidade`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create a relation for OS object in your Laudo e.g.,

```
type Laudo struct {     
gorm.Model  
NumOsID           string        `json:"num_os"` 
DataLaudo         time.Time    `json:"data_laudo"`  
JustificativaID   int          `json:"JustificativaID"` 
Justificativa     Justificativa`gorm:"foreignKey:JustificativaID"`  
FunciAcompanhante string       `json:"funci_acompanhante"`  
SituacaoID        int          `json:"situacaoID"`  
Situacao          Situacao     `gorm:"foreignKey:SituacaoID"`   
Anexos            []Arquivo    `json:"anexos"`
OsID              int          `json:"osID"`  
Os                Os           `json:"os" gorm:"foreignKey:OsID;references:your_primary_or_reference_variable_name_here"`
}
```

this will create you a relation with your os based on OSID and what ever reference you give